# Sort from terminal is not working properly

Tags: command-line, sort

I am trying to sort a text file by its second column. All the text in the file is in `word /t number` format (a word, tab, and it's weight). I am trying to sort the file by it's second column, by weight but the results are not good. The file is in read & write.

The command I am using is `sort -k2,2nr`. (or change n for g or h).

No luck with either of them.

example of few lines, maybe the format matters:

```
00001930-n      7.18509e-06
00001740-n      4.35957e-05 
00002137-n      1.13377e-05
00002452-n      7.73398e-06
00002684-n      0.000244948 
00003553-n      3.98312e-05
00003993-n      3.98321e-07
```

some results here: seems like the exponent is not taken care of.
(these numbers are created using `sort -k2,2nr filename`.

```
02052204-n      3e-06  
01975237-v      1.2e-06  
02288155-v      1.2e-06  
15105733-n      1.4e-06  
00962135-a      1.6e-06  
09719309-n      1.9e-06  
02998269-a      2.5e-05  
11938977-n      3.1e-06  
14498972-n      3.6e-06  
03341153-n      5.4e-07  
01908703-n      6.5e-06  
00257026-r      1.02e-06  
08111599-n      1.03e-05
```

Answer (score 3):

You have the options swapped around, you need:

```
sort -k2,2gr filename
```

- `k2,2` sets the key to sorting as the second field only; `g,r` is analogous to `-g` and `-r`, only difference is that this works only on the key when used like this

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm new to this. But still, the results are not properly sorted.

Comment: @txorimalo For any `locale` issue, you should run the `sort` command with `C` as `LC_COLLATE` to fix the collation order: `LC_COLLATE=C sort -k2,2gr filename`

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I'm sorry it had nothing to do with the sort function, but I'll leave an answer in case someone has the same problem.

The problem was the locale. I'm from Spain and even if my OS language and some more options were in `en_US.UTF-8`, the numeric was in `es_ES.UTF-8`. I changed that locale value and the sort worked. (I guess it has something to do with the punctuation mark.)